# Unable to install DeployR Open 8.0.0 on Windows 10

Tags: r, deployr, microsoft-r, rro

I am trying to install DeployR Open 8.0.0 on Windows 10 (64 bits). I have installed the following dependencies:

1. JRE 8
2. Revolution R Open 3.2.2 and MKL (RevoMath 3.2.2)
3. DeployR Rserve 7.4.2

I followed the install instructions for [RRO & MKL](https://mran.microsoft.com/archives/install-doc/rro-3.2.2/) and [DeployR](https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/admin/install/#preparing-win). I have also done a clean install, that is prior to installing all these stuff, I uninstalled R, and RStudio.

However, when start installing DeployR Open 8.0.0 (even as Administrator), it is unable to find the dependencies/prerequisites, and on clicking next it opens [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/deployr-about), which more or less talks about the same set of dependencies.

Here are the screenshots:
[image: Prerequisite screenshot 1]
[image: Prerequisite screenshot 2]

I am not sure what I am missing here. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same here. I have all prerequesties on my computer, but when I try to install, I get an error message: Microsoft RServer(not installed) and Java Runtime Environment (not installed)

Comment: @Kaja I have already abandoned that way. However, if you can use SQL-Server 2016, you can also run the your r script from SQL Server. The advantage is that all your data and data analytics model are at the same place. I never got time to try that out though I am very interested to look into that. Not sure if it is feasible for you or not, just in case you are interested here is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r-services/using-r-code-in-transact-sql-sql-server-r-services

Comment: Thanks. I have got it. DeployR is an extra possibility für R Server 8.0.5, if you have R Server 9.0, then you dont need DeployR, because functionalities of DeployR are embeded in R Server 9.0 under the name of "opertionalzitation".  You can not use R Server 9.0 and DeployR

Comment: @Kaja Thanks for the information, I will certainly try this out.